# How can i send some value from detailView to a masterView in a splitView controller?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a table on the masterView and some buttons on the detailView. so when i click some button, based on the button click the masterTable should load???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may design a interface as ** detailViewDelegate**

then implement in ** masterView**

Comment: ... what i am talking about is "protocal"

Comment: sorry even i meant the same :)